# How resolve an error "Unable to write" when permissions are good

Tags: php, symfony, permissions

I've a project and on this project we've 3 way to upload a file :

- When the user want to upload an avatar.
- When the user want to upload a cover.
- When the user want to upload an image on his gallery.

When I'm on the prod and the user want to upload an image for his avatar or his cover, they're no problems and everything work. But when I want to upload an image for his gallery, I've an error 500.
When I'm on a dev it's work. The problem is on prod.
I've read the prod.log file and this is the error :

```
[2020-07-05 01:56:46] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException: "Unable to write in the "/var/www/computer/html/project/public/gallery/images/" directory" at /var/www/computer/html/project/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php line 112 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\Exception\\FileException(code: 0): Unable to write in the \"/var/www/computer/html/project/public/gallery/images/\" directory at /var/www/computer/html/project/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php:112)"} []
```

I don't understand why I've this error for the gallery but not for the avatar or the cover.
The directory /cache have permissions with a chmod 777.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Maybe you need to change the permissions (or ownerships) of /images which seems to be where the file is being uploaded to.

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem! Now that's work perfectly!
Thank you very much!